# PHP: how to add image?

Tags: php

The simplest question but I can't get it working... What's wrong with the way I'm trying to add an image to this php file?

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>

<h1 class="error"><?php echo t('Page Not Found')?></h1>

<?php echo t('We could not find a page at this address.')?>

<?php  if (is_object($c)) { ?>
    <br/><br/>
    <?php  $a = new Area("Main"); $a->display($c); ?>
<?php  } ?>

<?php
    echo "<img src="img.jpg">"
?>

<a href="<?php echo DIR_REL?>/"><?php echo t('Back to Home')?></a>.
```

The file named `img.jpg` sits in the same directory as this `.php` file. When it runs, I see this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in line 21` where line 21 is `echo "<img src="img.jpg">"`.

Comment: Semi-colon and quotes `echo "<img src='img.jpg'>";` or `echo "<img src=\"img.jpg\">";`

Comment: Basic PHP syntax. `echo "foo"bar""` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two, or possibly three, things are wrong with the way you're adding an image.

- You need to use different kinds of quotation marks (`"` vs `'`), otherwise they cancel each other out.
- You need a `;` to end the line in PHP
- Your image path may be broken.  If `img.jpg` is not in the same directory as the PHP script, it won't work.

Replace:

```
"<img src="img.jpg"/>"
```

with

```
"<img src='img.jpg'/>";
```

If the problem is with your image path, try using an absolute path (`src="http://example.com/your/path/img.jpg"`) instead of the relative path (`src="img.jpg"`).  If that works, then it means that the relative path was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

instead of :

```
echo "<img src="img.jpg">";
```

you can do:

```
echo "<img src='img.jpg'>";
```

or

```
echo '<img src="img.jpg">';
```

or even escape the quote:

```
echo "<img src=\"img.jpg\">";
```

Comment: This `echo "<img src=\"img.jpg\">"` removed the error I was seeing, but displays an empty rectangle.

Comment: well you need to make sure it's in the same folder as this php

Comment: This `echo '<img src="img.jpg">'` also removed the error, but shows an empty rectangle.

Comment: make sure the image path and name is correct, also the extensions

Comment: Yes, in same folder. But page is accessed from CMS system, so there may be something involved there I'm not aware of. I tried `./img.jpg` and `/home/user/full/path/to/file/img.jpg` but height helped.

Comment: dont forget semi colon `;` at the end of the statemen

Comment: When you look at the source code in the resulting page, do you see an image tag at all?  What happens if you specify an absolute path to the image?

Comment: Doesn't work: `echo "<img src='/home/user/path/to/file/img.jpg'>";`. Also doesn't work: `echo "<img src='/home/user/path/to/file/img.jpg'/>";`. Don't we need the `/>` to close the img tag?

Comment: @ggkmath You can check whether the issue is with your PHP or your image tag by putting the image tag outside your PHP (`<img src="your/path/img.jpg" />`).  What happens then?  Also, the path you put is still relative to the current directory - try writing the path with reference to the website itself (`src="http://example.com/your/path/img.jpg"`).

Comment: The source code includes the text I wrote in the file. The absolute path is there. In firefox, it gives me the option to click the link, which then shows a 404 file not found error. The path is correct (I cut and paste it in). Perhaps permissions? Not sure. The CMS might be messing something up.

Comment: @ggkmath in addtion to ASGM's suggestion please try with another image for example `http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

Comment: Ahh, your comment about including the path starting from `http://mydomain.com` solved it!  Still confused on whether `/>` is required to close the HTML `<img` tag. It seems to work with or without the `/`.

Comment: @ggkmath, great! I've added that to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong quotation on the  `img` line and then I suggest keeping it all in PHP. You can replace your code with this code which is more easy to read and maintain:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
echo '<h1 class="error">'. t('Page Not Found') .'</h1>';
echo t('We could not find a page at this address.');

if (is_object($c)) {
    echo '<br /><br />';
    $a = new Area("Main");
    $a->display($c);
}

echo "<img src='img.jpg'>";
echo '<a href="'. DIR_REL .'/">'. t('Back to Home') .'</a>.';
```